# Python and Photoshop

Tags: python, photoshop

I have used python to write script for Photoshop using versions from CS6 to CC 2014 and my scripts have worked flawlessly. Last week I updated my Photoshop to CC 2015 and my scripts stopped working. I got error messages about missing attributes. I thought this was due to CC 2015 having changed something about the COM interface. When I checked the available attributes, I noticed that only a small subset of all the attributes was avilabe.

I then reinstalled the CC 2014 but the problem did not disappear, I still see just a small subset of the attributes, all the rest gave the same error message. I noticed the splash screen had changed from my previous version of CC 2014 which may mean that some changes has been made in my newer CC 2014 as well.

I can still run the script on my old machine with CS6.

I have of course run makepy prior to using the new Ps version.

I have tried two approaches: win32com and comtypes. Neither works. I get different sets of exported methods for the win32com and comtypes approaches which is surprising.

I am very dependent on my scripts and would like to find a solution.

If you are using Photoshop CC 2014 with python, I recommend you don't upgrade until this problem is solved.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To make this question more likely to be answered you can add the error messages and the failing scripts to your question. Here's why this is important: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Most people won't have PS, but will be able to troubleshoot error messages.

Comment: This issue seems linked to the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45174628/photoshop-cc-2017-python).

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is due to a change in the Photoshop API.
You may want to report it to them and get the right feedback.

Since most of the stackflow user might be more "code-oriented", it is likely that you won't get effective answer.